# snowflake: How to know the list of all roles having usage grant on a schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I have a schema.

```
"DB1"."Schema"
```

Now i want to know all the roles having usage grant on this schema.

How can i find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out SHOW GRANTS: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html

With `SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA "DB1"."SCHEMA"` you can see all privileges, which have been granted.